# <nav> and <section> elements inside "container" div --- container disappears unless specific height in px is stated

Tags: html, css, height, containers

I'm a complete html/css newbie and I'm making my first site. I want it to look something like this:

http://www.dorishochscheid.nl/

I used a div element to "contain" the navigation bar and the main content, like this:

```
<div id = "container">
<nav> ... working navigation bar here ... </nav>
<section id = "content"> ... main content here ... </section>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
body {
background-image: url(images/achtergrond.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom center;
margin: 0;
}

#container {
margin: 0 auto 0;
margin-bottom: 200px;
width: 800px;
height: 1000px;
background-color: #de59b2;
opacity:0.85;
/* voor slechte browsers */
filter: alpha(opacity=85);
}

#content {
float: left;
background-color: #de59b2;
margin: 15px 45px;
}
```

The navigation bar, the content section and the container all have the same opaque background color.

The problem is this: I want the container div to grow in height according to how much content is placed in the content section. But if I remove the height = 1000px; the whole container disappears from sight. Seperate colored boxes for the navigation bar and main section remain.

Why does this happen?? I've seen things like height = 100%; being used, but that doesn't work here either. I can imagine such a statement being what I'm looking for, seeing how I want the container to grow with the content section.

Why does this happen and how do I get the container to size up or down depending on the amount of content in the content section that it contains?

Or is this totally the wrong way to go about this type of contruction?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the content floats. That keeps the container from adjusting to fit the content. Simply add this to your container:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes things clear. I just removed the float: left; instruction for #content and things work fine! Didn't really know what it was doing there anyway...